# Variable does not exist?

Tags: java

So, I have some fairly simple code, but in the second class, neither method can find `name`. Is this a simple issue of scope?

```
package rpg;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Start {
    static String name;
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Engine test12 = new Engine();
        name = test12.gameStart();
        System.out.println("So, " + name + " it is!");
    }       
}
```

Which calls this class:

```
package rpg;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Engine {
    static boolean playerNameLike = false;
    String name = (" ");

    public String gameStart()
    {
        while (playerNameLike = false)
        {
            System.out.println("So, whats your name?");
            Scanner gameStart = new Scanner(System.in);
            name = (gameStart.next());
            nameTest();
        }
        return name;
    }

    public boolean nameTest()
    {
        System.out.println("Does " + name + " sound good?");
        System.out.println("(Y)es or (N)o?");
        Scanner gameStart = new Scanner(System.in);
        String yesNo = new String (gameStart.next());
        if (yesNo.equals("Y"))
        {
            playerNameLike = true;
            return playerNameLike;
        } 
        if (yesNo.equals("N"))
        {
            playerNameLike = false;
            return playerNameLike;
        }
        return playerNameLike;
    }
 }
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: This loop will never be executet: `while (playerNameLike = false)` do you mean `while (!playerNameLike)` which is the same as `while (playerNameLike == false)` ??

Comment: @jlordo Yeah, that's an issue. Fixed, though it doesn't affect the `name` issue.
@JoachimSauer `name cannot be resovled to a variable`

Comment: static variable modified in a non-static method is not really a good design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make `name` a local variable in the `gameStart` method, and pass it to `nameTest` as a parameter, like this:

```
public String gameStart()
{
    String name = "";
    boolean playerNameLike = false;
    while (!playerNameLike)
    {
        System.out.println("So, whats your name?");
        Scanner gameStart = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = (gameStart.next());
        playerNameLike  = nameTest(name);
    }
    return name;
}

public boolean nameTest(String name) // Use your current code from here on
```

Also, you are assigning `false` to the variable in the `if` statement. This is allowed, but it does not do what you want. You should either use `==`, or (better) use `!` to negate the variable:

```
while (!playerNameLike) ...
```

Comment: Name being the class variable, shouldn't it be available in `nameTest()` method?

Comment: @YogendraSingh It's a class variable in an unrelated class. Although it can certainly be accessed, the intent of `gameStart` is different.

Comment: I see it in `Engine` class itself: `String name = (" ");`

Comment: @YogendraSingh Ah, I re-formatted the code, and I can see it now. I edited the answer to take this into account. Thank you very much!

Comment: `name` look good now but now I am thinking about `playerNameLike`, which is again a class variable that also static. Just sharing the observation per your advice that define `name` as local.

Comment: The second name variable still can't be found, in `return name;`.
Also, could anyone explain what !(variable) does?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I did, and the return name is saying
`The local variable name may not have been initialized`

Comment: @Cowthulhu Ah, I see! Please add an initial value then. You should also move the `playerNameLike` variable inside the function (I made an edit to the answer again to show how you can do it).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It works perfectly, and I actually understand what I did wrong! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` to compare in the condition as:

```
 while (playerNameLike == false)
```

or just check the negation of it as its a boolean type:

```
 while (!playerNameLike)
```

Also, move the `Scanner` instantiation outside the `while` loop as:

```
 Scanner gameStart = new Scanner(System.in);
 while (!playerNameLike)
 {
    System.out.println("So, whats your name?");
    name = (gameStart.next());
    nameTest();
  }
```

Comment: @Cowthulhu: `name` being a class variable of `Engine` class, it should directly be available to `nameTest` method same as `playerNameLike` variable, so no need to change the method signature for this. Though, if `playerNameLike` method is for local use then no need to return the value from it as you are updating the class variable `playerNameLike` which is again available in your first method.